# C++ Circular linked list error

Tags: c++11, circular-list

Can anyone help me to point out and explain the logical error that I have in this circular linked list code? Thanks in advance.

```
template <class xtype>  
void clist<xtype>:: copylist (const clist<xtype> & other)  
{  
    node<xtype> *temp;  
    node<xtype> *p;  

    if (head !=NULL)  
        makeEmpty();  
    if (other.head == NULL)
        head = NULL;  
    else  
    {  
        p = other.head;  
        head = new node<xtype>;  

        head->info = p->info;  
        temp = head;  

        p = p->next;  

        while(p != head)  
        {  
             temp->next = new node<xtype>;
             temp = temp->next;  
             temp->info = p->info;  
             p = p->next;  
        }  
        temp->next = head;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick look at your code, and I spot this:

```
while(p != head)
```

You should be testing `other.head`, not `head`.

Comment: but why use other.head instead of head?

Comment: @user3504938 Because `p` is iterating through the `other` list.  `head` itself is in the list that you are creating, and should never be encountered by traversing `other`.